# How to select duplicate document number? SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have quite hard question(for me:D). I have a column with document nr, which is either like 0001, either 1. Of course it's not all same like this, it can be string too, and more 0 before. My task is to select the duplicated document nr (in my case, 00001 = 1). I'm killing myself here. Please help me if you can! Thank you very much!

Comment: What datatype is the id column?

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
select regexp_replace(id,'^0*([^0]+)','\1') id_modified,
       count(*) 
from document
group by regexp_replace(id,'^0*([^0]+)','\1')
having count(*) > 1;
```

Or much easier:

```
select ltrim(id,'0') id_modified,
       count(*) 
from document
group by ltrim(id,'0')
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on MySQL ([See fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b44c2/5)):

```
SELECT COUNT(1), CAST(DocumentID AS SIGNED) 
FROM Document
GROUP BY CAST(DocumentID AS SIGNED) 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

`CAST` the value as an integer (which removes trailing 0s), and then use the `COUNT(1)` + `GROUP BY DocumentID` with a `HAVING` clause to find any documentid existing more than once.

For SQL Server ([See fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d2869/2)), replace `SIGNED` with `int`:

**UPDATE:** For Oracle

The same query as SQL Server should also work in Oracle. Pasting it here to ensure the answer will reflect the proper syntax rather than just by linkage:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS IDCount, CAST(DocumentID AS int) AS DupeDocumentID
FROM Document
GROUP BY CAST(DocumentID AS int) 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Comment: I'm working with SQL Developer...it's not working for me...but from what i understand from this code, is that we already know about 1, and try to search for it in other context(sorry for my not great english, hope you understand...). I don't have nothing for comparison...

Comment: Sorry about saying that it isn't working...i've tried with other values beside 1 and it's working...but how to modify to work for me? Thank you!

Comment: I modified the code with my columns and it showed me this ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

Comment: Isn't the engine is ORACLE??

Comment: Here's an example for ORACLE. I'll add the query to the answer.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5463a/1

Comment: @realspirituals - It is, but that was not known until the mentioning of the "SQL Developer". At that time I had the MySQL and SQL Server examples in the answer already.

Comment: Now I see the point. I raised it because I was expecting to see some Oracle answers.